# How to find the text in an NSTextView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nstextview

I need to find the text in an `NSTextView`, and save it to a file. I can do the saving fine. I have used `-stringValue`, and `-textStorage` so far, but neither have worked. When I put `-stringValue` in, it just gave me (null), and when I put `-textStorage` in, it gave me a very large chunk of nothing (like a long paragraph of invisible text).

How can I put the text from an `NSTextView` into an `NSString`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try

```
NSString *text = [[myTextView textStorage] string];
```

The NSTextStorage inherits from [NSMutableAttributedString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableAttributedString) which inherits from [NSAttributedString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSAttributedString). The latter implements the [string](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000166-string) method.

This isn't too obvious if you just look at the NSTextView's instance methods in the documentation.

Comment: Nothing is happening. I just get an "invisible paragraph". EDIT: I made it do an `NSLog`, and it showed me the right string. The file I saved doesn't show anything but that "large invisible paragraph" that I talked about. What now?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
[myTextView string];
```

If you are struggling to write the textView stringValue into a file try something like this:

```
    [[myTextView string] writeToFile:@"someFile" atomically:YES encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:&error];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have tried that. I'm starting to think that I made an error somewhere else, but I can't think of anything that could cause this. EDIT: I just did a quick scan and I found the problem. I am saving a lot of different things, and I forgot a "%@" in my `-stringWithFormat` section.

Answer (score 1):

when setting value, use `text.string = @"XXXX";`
when getting value, use `STRING = [text.string copy];`

because if you forget copy, the `mutableString` will be deliver to `STRING`. This will raise bugs when you editing multiple things with a single `textview`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to compile all of the information for anyone else with this question, I am answering my own question. If I am not allowed to do this, please tell me.

The code is actually extremely simple.

Files.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface Files : NSObject {
    IBOutlet id dataToSave;
}

- (IBAction) saveData: (id) sender;
```

Files.m

```
@implementation Files

- (IBAction) saveData: (id) sender; {
    NSString *text = [[dataToSave  textStorage] string];
    NSLog(@"%@", text);
    [text writeToFile:@"Users/justin/Desktop/test.txt atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
}
```

Instead of voting this up, vote for the other two people that answered this.